# Apache camel rest service

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

Here is my code:

```
<route id="GetPersonDetails">
        <description>To get details of a person </description>
        <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8345/details/getDetails" />
        <bean ref="PersonalDetails" method="getPersonDetails" />
</route>
```

My method "getPersonDetails" takes a "person" name as input and displays that person details.

I am trying invoke URL like:

http:xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8345/details/getDetails(${header.name})='John'

I don't know how to invoke this link. Please correct (help) me with proper syntax and examples. I am new to Camel.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,  just to make it easier if it is on your local machine write localhost instead.  Makes it clearer to understand.

To actually send requests use tools such as postman for Chrome,  curl or fiddler and add your URL and body and test.

Easiest is to deploy the project as camel context without test just to see what happens.. Logs should give you the details.